# How to achieve Python like string strip in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, string, strip

In Python, I can strip white-spaces, new lines or random characters from strings like

```
>>> '/asdf/asdf'.strip('/')
'asdf/asdf' # Removes / from start
>>> '/asdf/asdf'.strip('/f')
'asdf/asd' # Removes / from start and f from end
>>> ' /asdf/asdf '.strip()
'/asdf/asdf' # Removes white space from start and end
>>> '/asdf/asdf'.strip('/as')
'df/asdf' # Removes /as from start
>>> '/asdf/asdf'.strip('/af')
'sdf/asd' # Removes /a from start and f from end
```

But Ruby's [String#strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/String.html#method-i-strip) method accepts no arguments. I can always fall back to using regular expressions but is there a method/way to strip random characters from strings (rear and front) in Ruby without using regular expressions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
"atestabctestcb".gsub(/(^[abc]*)|([abc]*$)/, '')
# => "testabctest"
```

Of course you can make this a method as well:

```
def strip_arbitrary(s, chars)
    r = chars.chars.map { |c| Regexp.quote(c) }.join
    s.gsub(/(^[#{r}]*)|([#{r}]*$)/, '')
end

strip_arbitrary("foobar", "fra") # => "oob"
```

Comment: Thanks for awesomely concise answer. But it seems there is no way to avoid regexes.

Comment: @Kulbir: Of course you can avoid regex here, it's just not going to be as concise ;) I think this is because the Python function is a bit special.

Comment: Yes, I guess avoiding regex would include looping on the characters and stripping them individually. But this works as well.

Comment: Yeah, I think it'd get a bit messy without regex

Answer (score 4):

Python's strip is a little unusual. It removes any characters that match any of those in the argument from either end.

I think you need 2 `.subs`. One to strip from the beginning and one to strip from the end

```
irb(main):001:0> 'asdf/asdf'.sub(/^[\/]*/, '').sub(/[\/]*$/, '')
=> "asdf/asdf"
irb(main):002:0> 'asdf/asdf'.sub(/^[\/f]*/, '').sub(/[\/f]*$/, '')
=> "asdf/asd"
irb(main):003:0> ' asdf/asdf'.sub(/^[ ]*/, '').sub(/[ ]*$/, '')
=> "asdf/asdf"
```